# purpose of using onProgressUpdate() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

why should we use onProgressUpdate() method in Asynctask class,
i am using onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() along with doInBackground() but never used onProgressUpdate,In which cases we will use this method.
Thanks in Advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`, invoked on the UI thread after a call
>   to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>   undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>   user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>   For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>   a text field.

As you read, you can publish your async task progress by using this.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     showProgressPercent(progress[0]);//write your own codes
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: yaa..i got it..Thanks for ua response

Answer (score 0):

`onProgressUpdate()` is used to better the user experience by updating the user about the background process initiated at some time. For more information, refer to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)).

Comment: yaa..i got it..Thanks for ua response

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask lifecycle : **onPreExecute -> doInBackground -> onPostExecute**

- **onPreExecute** is calling on MainThread. which means you can touch views.
- **doInBackground** is calling on BackgroundThread. which means you can't touch views.
- **onPostExecute** is calling on MainThread.

so while your job is going on inside doInBackground, you may want to **notify user** about job's progress but you can't notify user because it's calling on BackgroundThread. you need to jump to MainThread and AsyncTask provides you **onProgressUpdate** function to make it.

you can call **publishProgress** inside doInBackground.

Comment: yaa..i got it..Thanks for ua response